# How to find the first hand exception that only shows up in the log?

Tags: java, c#, exception, access-violation

I stumbled upon some weird behavior in our product - every once in a while (ranger from several minutes to a couple of days), our log (a simple .txt file that we usually write our specific logs to) shows this message:

```
******************************************************
****** Warning - First Chance Exception Caught! ******
******************************************************
Process Name       : C:\OurApp.exe
Process ID         : 27396
Thread ID          : 21616
Debugger Time      : 11:45:34.073 24/10/2017
Exception Code     : 0xC0000005 - EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
Exception Desc     : The thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access.
Extended Desc      : The thread attempted to read inaccessible data.
Extended Desc 2    : Virtual address of inaccessible data 0xC
Exception Address  : 0x100517E2
Resolved Address   :    <no module>  (No symbol)  [0x100517E2]
Stack Trace        :

    <no module>  (No symbol)  [0x85C5A7D8]
    Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing (symbol not found)

******************************************************
```

Other than that, no special behavior is noticeable - it was first reported as a crash, but apparently it doesn't crash, just prints this to the log from time to time. It's not one of our logs, and this warning isn't in any of the code files (I scanned the whole repo, not just the specific project). It gets printed no matter what's the log level.
 
I also couldn't find this message in any documentation (our app is written in c#, but there might be imported modules written in C++/Java), so as of now I'm not sure how do I find the culprit and how do I stop this from happening.
I'm sure that a process spawned by OurApp.exe writes this to the log (checked it with procmon).
Any ideas how can I find what makes it happen and how to stop it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Question: Do you have [User Account Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) turned on for the machine that is running this application?

Comment: @gmiley Yes, I do.

Comment: Can you try running with it disabled? If you can't make this change on your production environment, can you reproduce the issue in a different environment and then try disabling to see if that corrects the issue. [Here is the article](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/exception_access.xml) that discusses the issue. You can alternatively ensure all of your related software (libraries/drivers/etc) are updated to the latest UAC compatible versions.

Comment: By what means does this exception get reported in the log? Are you using a trace listener for example, or something else?

Comment: @gmiley will try this, thanks.

Comment: @BensaysNotoPoliticsonSO I mean the log created specifically for our app - a txt (or .log, to be precise) file that we write to using fprint in c++ (of course, we have a wrapper to build the format of the log, but basically it's just printing to a preset text file).

Comment: @A.Pet then probably you have an Exception Filter somewhere in your C++ code which is logging first-chance exceptions. Point: First Chance Exceptions are not necessarily problems. Are there any associated symptoms?

Comment: @BensaysNotoPoliticsonSO there are no associated symptoms, at all. If the root of this is in our code - shouldn't I be able to see this message (or parts of it) in the code or the .exe? I tried finding this log's text (both whole and parts of it) in the code and in the exe's (using sysinternals strings.exe), without success. That's why I suspect it's something on the OS level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as it's only a first-chance exception, and there are no associated negative symptoms it's probably fine.

This is an SEH (Stuctured Exception Handling) "First Chance Exception", which is an operating system feature on Windows.

With SEH, the exception filter (usually C or C++ code) has the option to attempt to recover from the "first chance" exception without unwinding the stack.

Only if no exception filter offers to recover does the exception finally get "thrown" like a C++, Java, or C# exception.

It is quite normal for first-chance `0xC0000005` exceptions to be used by OS level code (or native code libraries) as a way of initialising code or data on first use. For example they are used for delay-load DLLs - the first time you call the function you get a first-chance exception, the exception filter loads the DLL, then tells the OS to retry.

Psychic Debugging:

You probably have code somewhere which does this:

```
intptr LogException(LPEXCEPTION_POINTERS pep){
    // Log the exception
    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
}

__try{
    // Some code
}
__except(LogException(GetExceptionInformation())){}
```

You could probably improve your "LogException" to extract more information from the exception record.

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363082(v=vs.85).aspx

You are already retrieving some of the extended data.

In your specific case the faulting address appears to be 0xC. That may be a sentinel value, but it also looks suspiciously like you have called a C++ object through a null pointer.

Thinking more, the fact that there is no module and no symbols suggests this is JIT-ed code belonging to Java or C#. If that's the case it's possible you have passed in or returned a null pointer when you should have used an array or struct, possibly either in a JNI or P/Invoke method (but it could also be a COM method).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed comment! I will definitely read up a bit more about the Structured Exception Handling you mentioned. 
It is probably nothing serious, as I said - the program continues working fine with no other symptoms but this log, and as far as I saw - all of the possible exceptions get handled eventually, one way or another. Still, to gracefully close this issue, I want to find the root of the problem - even if it's a specific OS call in the end.

Comment: Will look into it. Maybe it gets constructed in a weird way. Thanks!

Comment: You were right - there was and exception handler with this behavior, that had nothing that could have hinted me on its purpose unless I knew what I was looking for. Thank you very much for the help, especially for the code snippet!

Comment: If it's an option for you, consider including debug symbols in the JIT-ed code. This is separate from optimisation and won't affect the speed, but may make it easier to trace the source. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/making-an-image-easier-to-debug Presumably Java has similar options.